# After Expire certificate, is it necessary to create a new Pushnotification based provisioning profile at apple

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification

I am using push notification based application with apply all the required information related to a push notification based application.
Now i want to know that after revoke or expiration of the certificate of user, is it necessary to create a new provisioning profile with new push notification enabled profile.

What are the limitations of the push notification based profiles in iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't have to. 
Unless you will update your app, you can continue to do push notifications without renewing any provisioning profiles. All you have to do is renew p12 file that is used at backend side. You can find many tutorials on the web about how to create p12 file for push licenses.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, your profile needs to exist AND it needs to be valid for push notifications to be delivered.